# How to set up many-to-many with additional fields in my case

Tags: python, django, django-orm

There are 3 models: Item, Offer, and RatingAndReviews. Customers create tasks for contractors, the are stored in Items, contractors make an offer in Offer for a task. Items can have multiple offers. After the task is done customers leave a rating and a review for contractor. What is the best way to create models

```py
class Item(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    offers = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Offer',
        through='RatingAndReview'
    )

class Offer(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

class RatingAndReview(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    offer = models.ForeignKey(Offer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    review = models.TextField()
```

I used to have a one-to-many relationship Item - Offer and could choose an owner of Offer and an Item i am making it for, but had to add RatingAndReview. Now when i create an Offer in django-admin i can't access an Item to choose it for.
Do my models look fine? How can i access an Item when creating an Offer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few ideas to make it work:

- If an offer is related to *one* item, there should be an `item` foreign key (FK) in `Offer` and no M2M field `offers` in `Item`.
- You have to decide if ratings are for items or offers, and leave only one FK in `Review`, it doesn't make sense to have two when there is already a relationship between `Offer` and `Item`.
- You need some way of specifying the "winning" bid, e.g. as a `selected_offer` field on `Item`. This also helps with linking reviews to bids and bidders if you choose to limit reviews to items rather than offers.